# Adobe Air app for iOS only works in interpreter mode?

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I have an Adobe Air application that I am packaging for iOS.

If the `target` is `ipa-debug-interpreter` or `ipa-test-interpreter` the app works just fine. However, any other target it crashes when trying to use assets. I have seen the following exception:

```
[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable FlexVersion is not defined.
Fault, SpriteAsset() at SpriteAsset.as:131
131               if (appDomain.hasDefinition("mx.core::FlexVersion"))
```

Other times it will crash with no stack.

Why would it only work when the target includes interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Packaging with interpreter is faster than the regular debug packaging (not that I've ever noticed a timetable difference). I would hazard a guess that for it to be faster it must bypass certain processes which the normal debug would check for. From the type of error you're getting I would suggest you double check your manifest XML file for missing packages and/or the version of the AIR SDK you are targeting. Hope this provides some help.

**EDIT:** May also be worth revision which version of the FLEX SDK you are targeting and this can cause issues of this kind.